# Devices aren't both available when connected through a switch

Tags: windows, networking, ip, ethernet, switch

I have the following situation:

- `Computer` (with Windows) with a single ethernet port, with the config below (*)
- `DeviceA`, configured with fixed IP 192.168.254.254, connected alone to `Computer` with an ethernet cable.

  It works: we can connect the device's web interface in a browser at http://192.168.254.254
- `DeviceB`, configured with fixed IP 169.254.0.1, connected alone to the same `Computer` with an ethernet cable (when DeviceA is unplugged).
  It works: we can connect the device's web interface too.

  Note: this IP 169.254.xx.xx is in the  [APIPA](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Private_Internet_Protocol_Addressing) range (Automatic Private Internet Protocol Addressing).

Now if I connect both `DeviceA` and `DeviceB` **to a switch** ([Hirschmann Spider SL 20](https://www.hirschmann-multimedia.com/fr-BE/artnr/942132001/spider-sl-20-05t1999999sy9hhhh)), which is connected to the `Computer`'s ethernet port, then:

- `DeviceA` works
- `DeviceB` doesn't work (unreachable)
- We can see that the computer network adapter on Windows has been automatically configured with a 192.169.xx.xx in the adapter settings (menu "Properties").

**Question**: **How to make both devices A and B available from the computer, through the switch?**

I thought that using a switch wouldn't change anything to IP address configuration.
Is it normal that using a switch requires to modify the devices' static IP configuration?

---

(*) Config:

[image]

Comment: What's the _effective_ IP configuration of the computer? Your "config" screenshot only shows that it's set to obtain the address automatically, but what address _did_ it obtain automatically, as shown in `ipconfig /all`?

Comment: @user1686 I'll check tomorrow and I will post the IP, but as I remember, the address the computer automatically obtained was 192.168.xx.xx.

Comment: 1) From where does it "automatically obtain" it if there is no router etc. there? 2) Can you try configuring DeviceB with a 192.168.x.x IP in the same range as Computer and DeviceA?

Comment: @YisroelTech 2) Yes I will try this, and it will probably solve it, but I wanted to know if, in general, using a switch always implies to have to move the two devices in the same range? Also letting DeviceB in special APIPA range 169.254.x.x was quite handy, because if I connect this device to another computer, the fact that it's in this range makes that it's immediately available ([ZeroConf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking)) 1) I don't know, I will check. Isn't it automatic if you connect a 192.168.x.x device to an ethernet port? I always get an IP in such cases.

Comment: Most device are set to automatically obtain IP, and in that case when you connect the two devices directly (without a router/DHCP) they will work with zeroconf since they both get an APIPA IP address. So this shouldn't be an issue. The issue here is that the computer gets an IP (likely that DeviceA is a DHCP server) and therefore has an issue accessing other IP ranges (it is routed through the default gateway)

Comment: @YisroelTech You're probably right, DeviceA might act as a DHCP. 1) Can you elaborate the last part of your comment: why the gateway, what does the gateway do in this context?   2) In general, what happens when you connect an APIPA device to your computer with configuration [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQZhX.png)? Does the computer automatically get an IP address in the same APIPA range? Who gives this IP, especially in the case where neither the computer nor the device has a built-in DHCP server?

Comment: @Basj: The whole point of APIPA is that devices _self-configure_ the 169.254 addresses (specifically when nothing is available to offer DHCP) – the computer just unilaterally chooses an 169.254.x.x address and checks for conflicts. (Hence "zero"conf.) It doesn't even know whether there _are_ any other devices on the switch, nor whether any those devices also have an APIPA address or not (…unless they happen to conflict) – you'd get the same if you connected an "Auto" computer to a "Static IP" computer.

Comment: @user1686 `It doesn't even know whether the other device also has an APIPA address or not.` Are you sure? If the device on the other side of the ethernet cable had no APIPA address but a 10.0.0.1 address, would the computer really self-attribute an IP address?

Comment: "what does the gateway do in this context?", when a device has a default gateway all traffic that it doesn't know of a direct path and is not in its own IP range are sent to that IP address (and the default gateway is DeviceA), so your traffic to 169.254.0.1 goes to 192.168.254.254.  "Does the computer automatically get an IP address in the same APIPA range?" All of APIPA IPs are in the same range, and the computer gets an APIPA address - assured with ARP that it's not in use - by its own system if it doesn't get an IP. "...really self-attribute an IP address?" Yes, that's APIPA/zeroconf.

Comment: @Basj: Yes, it would still self-assign an APIPA address, if there was no DHCP server to offer something else. (It also wouldn't know whether the other device has an 10.0.0.1 address, either.) Generally, a device on Ethernet just doesn't know what IP addresses are held by other devices on the same Ethernet, unless it actually contacts them by address. Meaning, there's not really any way for a host to tailor its auto-assigned IP address according to what other device is connected… and that's literally why DHCP exists in the first place.

Comment: Something else to consider. Why does DeviceB never get an IP and remains with the APIPA address? Did you manually set the IP to that?

Comment: @YisroelTech: OP did explicitly mention it has a static address – merely one from the APIPA range, but a static address nevertheless. (And if I remember correctly, 169.254.0.x and 169.254.255.x are actually excluded from auto-assignment within the APIPA spec – meaning that 169.254.0.1 can *only* come from static config.)

Comment: In that case, the question is more like: why did you statically set the device to APIPA? Just let it on automatically obtain (if it has such option) and see if when not connected to a DHCP server it set itself an APIPA (which most DHCP clients would do.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought that using a switch wouldn't change anything to IP address configuration.
> Is it normal that using a switch requires to modify the devices' static IP configuration?

It's not the switch that changes the situation – it's the presence of `DeviceA`.

Most likely this is what happens:

- When `DeviceA` is present, `Computer` receives an IP address 192.168.254.x/24 via DHCP **offer from DeviceA** and considers itself to be in the 192.168.254.0/24 subnet.
- When `DeviceA` is **not** present, `Computer` receives no DHCP offers and auto-configures an IP address 169.254.x.x/16 via APIPA and considers itself to be in the 169.254.0.0/16 subnet.

The local subnet (address plus "subnet mask") is what tells the computer which other hosts are "local" or not; i.e. it's how the computer determines whether to send any given packet towards a router or towards the device itself.

- When `Computer` has the APIPA address and is in the 169.254.0.0/16 subnet, it considers `DeviceB` at 169.254.0.1 to be "local" – resolves its Ethernet address via ARP and sends the packets directly to DeviceB's MAC address.
- When `Computer` has the DHCP address and is in the 192.168.254.0/24 subnet, it **does not** consider 169.254.0.1 to be "local".

  If the DHCP lease provided a "default gateway", the computer sends the packet towards the *gateway's* MAC address (and the packet gets lost because DeviceA doesn't know any better where 169.254.0.1 is supposed to be, or perhaps it's not even configured to forward packets at all).

  If there was no "default gateway" provided, the computer just gives up and reports "Destination net unreachable".

To deal with this, you'll likely need to configure `Computer` with addresses from *both* subnets at the same time. (Unfortunately, on Windows this means both addresses need to be static – it can't do DHCP+APIPA and it can't even do DHCP+static.)

You can do this by first enabling static configuration (select "Use the following IP address"), then by opening "Advanced…" and adding **both** of the computer's addresses/masks to the list. Both addresses should then show up in `ipconfig /all` and the computer will understand that both subnets are "local" on the same interface.

Illustration (provided by OP after accepting the answer):

[image]

(Another sometimes suggested option might be to continue using DHCP for the 192.168.254.x/24 address but add a static route on the computer, telling it that 169.254.0.0/16 is in fact available locally; unfortunately such changes only work in one direction – a very likely result is that `Computer` would be able to send packets to `DeviceB`, but the device still wouldn't be able to *reply* to them, as Computer's address would still appear non-local from DeviceB's perspective.)

> Isn't it automatic if you connect a 192.168.x.x device to an ethernet port? I always get an IP in such cases.

If you connect an "192.168.x.x" device to an Ethernet port, that implies it was *statically* configured to be an 192.168.x.x device, so it's not quite that it "gets" an IP – it already has that IP.

If you connect an "Automatically configure" device, it doesn't get an 192.168.x.x address out of nowhere – only from another device on the network that would act as a DHCP server and would offer that address.

(Though, if the computer is set to "Automatically configure" but has 192.168.x.x on the "Alternate config" tab, that stilll counts as having it statically configured.)

APIPA addresses only show up if the computer *isn't* configured for 192.168.x.x (meaning it uses DHCP) and if the network has no DHCP server.

Comment: The poster does not specify that DeviceA is a DHCP server. If this is true, it is a very large omission by him. And why wouldn't DeviceB then receive an IP from DeviceA?

Comment: They didn't mention that (and I'm still waiting for that `ipconfig` output from OP), but there's nowhere else the computer could be getting an 192.168 address, and "192.168.254.254" _is_ an address used by several router models – which typically have DHCP. They did mention that DeviceB is statically configured, which means it won't be asking for an IP from DeviceA. (It _can_ be statically configured with an 169.254 address, even though that's a bit weird but there's nothing stopping it from being done… and APIPA even specifically excludes 169.254.0.x, so it can only come from static config.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think this explains everything in my situation! @harrymc About DHCP I don't know, I'll try to see if it is the case or not. I think user1686's guess is probably correct, so there is probably a DHCP I didn't know about.

Comment: Wonderful @user1686, I just checked, and all what you guessed (from my poor description!) was totally correct! Also your solution `You can do this by first enabling static [...] then by opening "Advanced…" and adding both of the computer's addresses/masks to the list` is perfect.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your help @harrymc and user1686!